# Deploying Go subpackages to Google Cloud Functions fails

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a function to GCF but it's failing no matter what I try. This is the error returned every time:

```
Build failed: 2021/03/02 18:02:46 Unable to extract package name: unable to find Go package in /workspace/serverless_function_source_code.
exit status 1; Error ID: aba1aa6a
```

I've read a few answers here and I tried to fix the issue as told, but I keep having this error and I'm lost at this point.

My project structure is as follow:

```
.
|--function.go
|--go.mod
|--go.sum
|--subpackage
`        |--subpackage.go
```

My main function uses some stuff from subpackage.go and the function.go import is:

```golang
package function

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    // remote imports //
    
    modname/subpackage
)
```

and then the go.mod file:

```
module modname

go 1.13

require (
    // remote imports //

    modname/subpackage
)
```

The subpackage is initialized as `package subpackage` and I think this is what the GCF docs say.

In function.go I have a function called Start that I indicated as the entrypoint in the setup. I'm lost and I have no idea how to work around this.

Comment: What's the content of your go.mod file?

Comment: It's at the end of the question.. the only thing is that instead of // remote imports // there are the URL of a few remote dependencies. Other than that there isn't anything else. _modname_ it's the name I gave to the module, _subpackage_ is the name of the package inside the folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. If you have my issue, ignore the go.mod file in my question, as it was rigthly suggested on an other answer that you should not include the local packages.

But my problem wasn't that. I was zipping and uploading the FOLDER containing the project, not the file inside the folder. GCF than unzipped the .zip and found an other folder with the project inside.

Your go.mod and function.go files have to be at the first level. Hope this will save time for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the reference of your `subpackage` in your `go.mod` file. When the `subpackage` is bellow the `function.go` file you don't need to reference it in the `go.mod` file.

Comment: That's how it was before I started looking for answers on StackOverflow and it wasn't working.